# asp.net form designing using css absolute position

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I was using table for designing forms for my web application.
But, it makes my markup messy as the control count increases. 
Can I use inline CSS(with absolute position, top, left specified) for form designing ? 
Will this make any performance impact ? Is there any tool, or technique to easily design Forms ?
Below is the current markup.

```
    <div style="position:relative;  height: 280px;width: 910px;"  class="employee-second-tab">
            <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top: 31px; left: 35px;" >Date of Birth:</asp:Label>
            <div  style="position:absolute; top: 30px; left: 123px;">
                 <asp:TextBox ID="dateOfBirth" runat="server" CssClass="datepicker" Width="155px"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
           <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top: 61px; left: 28px;" Text="Marital Status:"></asp:Label>
           <asp:DropDownList ID="maritalStatus" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top: 60px; left: 123px;" Width="180px">
               <asp:ListItem Value="-1">--SELECT--</asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem>Single</asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem>Divorced</asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem>Married</asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem>Widow(er)</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>

           <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top: 91px; left: 65px;" Text="Gender:"></asp:Label>
           <asp:RadioButton ID="genderMale" runat="server" Checked="True" 
            GroupName="gender" style="position:absolute; top: 90px; left: 123px;" 
            Text="Male" />
           <asp:RadioButton ID="genderFemale" runat="server" GroupName="gender"  style="position:absolute; top: 90px; left: 210px;" Text="Female" />

        <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top: 121px; left: 60px;"  Text="Children:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="children" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top: 120px; left: 123px;"  Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top: 151px; left: 33px;"  Text="Home Phone:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="homePhone" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top: 150px; left: 123px;"  Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top: 181px; left: 67px;" Text="Mobile:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="mobile1" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top: 180px; left: 123px;" 
            Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="mobile2" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top: 210px; left: 123px;" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="Label16" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top: 241px; left: 77px;" Text="Email:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="email" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top: 240px; left: 123px;" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="Label17" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top: 31px; left: 397px;" Text="Address:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="address1" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top: 30px; left: 460px;" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="address2" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top: 60px; left: 460px;" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="Label18" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top: 91px; left: 424px;" Text="City:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="city" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top: 90px; left: 460px;" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="Label19" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top: 121px; left: 403px;" Text="PO Box:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="poBox" runat="server" 
            style="position:absolute; top: 120px; left: 460px;" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:Label ID="Label20" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top: 151px; left: 416px;" Text="State:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="state" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top: 150px; left: 460px;" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:Label ID="Label21" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top: 181px; left: 393px;" Text="ZIP Code:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="zipCode" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top: 180px; left: 460px;" 
            Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:Label ID="Label22" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top: 211px; left: 400px;" Text="Country:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="country" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top: 210px; left: 460px;" Width="180px">
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:Label ID="Label23" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top: 241px; left: 383px;" Text="Nationality:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="nationality" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top: 240px; left: 460px;" Width="180px">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
```

Comment: What about using the `<dl>` `<dt>` `<dd>` tags?

Comment: its same like table right ? which I don't like..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your questions

> Can I use inline CSS(with absolute position, top, left specified) for
>   form designing ?

yes, you can

> Will this make any performance impact ?

no

> Is there any tool, or technique to easily design Forms ?

Visual Studio perfectly does it in design mode.

In general, you should stop using such layout. Suppose, you would be asked to get rid of the Date of Birth field. With current layout you will need to change coordinates of all following fields and labels to move them up. That will not happen if you would use html tables or divs. Another problem is that absolute positioning will not work well when window is resized or on small screens.

There is nothing special in your current form and you could easily do the same with

```
<table>
<tr>...</tr>
</table>
```

or

```
<div>...</div>
<div>...</div>
```

where you will be more flexible in coding.

Comment: Thanks smirnov. 
Can I set position at the Page_Init event of ASP.Net ?

Comment: You can use page_init/page_load, the question is why? Css should be separated from server code.

Comment: ok. I will create css classes like this .col1 {left:10px}
.col2 {left:20px} etc... 
and row1{top:10px;}.. etc
so that I can set the control class as class= 'col1 row2' etc :)

Comment: I wish if the css has ability to accept parameters, and set it to the styles :(

Comment: That will not change anything as you keep using absolute positioning.

Comment: I meant to say this.. 
Can you please check it 
https://jsfiddle.net/dassje/1jru1zo5/